# Checkbox value to be checked

Tags: php

My simple checkbox's code is the following:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="mycheckbox" value="1" <?php checked(1, get_option('mycheckbox'), true); ?> />
```

It works fine and values are being stored visually (if I check it, it remains checked and vice versa).

I am trying to set a variable, as a conditional logic, upon its value, but it seems to be failing:

```
if ( isset($_POST['mycheckbox']) ) {
    $isitchecked = 'yes';
} else {
    $isitchecked = 'no';
}
```

Echoing it, returns always 'no' even if it is checked.

Comment: Does the form have `method="POST"`?

Comment: What does `var_dump($_POST)` show?

Comment: @Barmar It always shows > array(0) { } and yes, form has POST method, form method="post" action="options.php"

Comment: Is this code inside something like `if (isset($_POST['submit']))`? If not, you'll execute it when you're first loading the page, before the form has been submitted.

Comment: @Barmar Not sure about which code you mean. I've followed a sample code (found here http://qnimate.com/add-checkbox-using-wordpress-settings-api/ ) in order to show a check box and now i am trying to set the value of it to a variable. If its checked, I want to have $var set to checked and if its not, to unchecked value.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, just solved this. The issue was related to the fact that the sample code I used was using WordPress Settings API, so I used this routine, in order to check my box:

```
  $options = get_option( 'mycheckbox' );

  // If is checked, activate function to display coming soon page
  if( $options['mycheckbox'] == '1' ) { 
      echo 'checked';
  } 
  else { 
      echo 'unchecked';
  }
```